# Picasso Image Loading in multithread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, picasso

I've been looking around to find a way to do Picasso in a separate thread as it is loading it from the internet. I have no idea how to confirm if it is.

My app is basically a ListView with one imageView and two textViews and I have created a CustomAdapter which extends BaseAdapter to assist the List. This is what I have done in my adapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
public String title[];
public String description[];
public String images[]; //Image URLs
private static Picasso instance;
public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;


public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description, String[] images) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.images = images;

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static Picasso getSharedInstance(Context context)
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Picasso.Builder(context).executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).memoryCache(Cache.NONE).indicatorsEnabled(true).build();
        return instance;
    }
    else
    {
        return instance;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView icon;
    TextView itemNameTextView;
    TextView itemDescriptionTextView;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Debug.startMethodTracing("ThreadCheck");
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(view==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.DownloadedImage);
        holder.itemNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ItemNameTextView);
        holder.itemDescriptionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ItemDescriptionTextView);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();


    Picasso.with(context).load(images[position]).into(holder.icon);

    holder.itemNameTextView.setText(title[position]);
    holder.itemDescriptionTextView.setText(description[position]);

    return view;
}

}
```

What I wanted to know was:

1) Does the following make Picasso to load the image in a seperate thread?
(I read this somewhere and it didn't really make sense to me and I'm hoping you guys would explain it to me.)

```
    instance = new Picasso.Builder(context).executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).memoryCache(Cache.NONE).indicatorsEnabled(true).build();
```

2) Or does

```
Picasso.with(context).load(images[position]).into(holder.icon);
```

automatically do it in a new thread?

3) Or does neither of these do it in a new thread and I need to do it seperately? If yes, how so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Picasso` downloads images from the Internet in a background thread by default. What do you want to confirm about it?

Comment: Yes it uses separated thread instead of UI thread for image loading.

Comment: Picasso downloads in a background thread, both with default context and using a builder... You will never get a NetworkOnMainThreadException..

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim Please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Picasso` downloads images from the Internet in a background thread by default. That's why we use such libraries for image loading.